# How to write following sibling CSS/Xpath expression of username field?

Tags: selenium, xpath, relative-locators

HTML Code:

```
<form autocomplete="on" xpath="1">
  <div class="IiD88i _351hSN">
     <input  class="_2IX_2- VJZDxU" autocomplete="off" type="text" value="">
     <span class="_36T8XR"></span>
```

I can write this one : `//input[@type='text']`

[image]

But how to write it in "following sibling" CSS/xpath of the above code?

Comment: Do you want CSS-selector or XPath? What do you mean by *"following sibling" xpath of the above code*? Following sibling of what? Also you need to update HTML sample  since it's hard to understand the structure

Comment: @JaSON I uploaded picture, I want both CSS and XPath in "following sibling" format.

Comment: Sibling relative to what? It should be a sibling of specific node... Which node? `span`, `label`..? `input` has no preceding siblings, so you cannot make an XPath with `following-sibling` axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fetch `input` node based on its sibling, try:

```
//label[.='Enter Email/Mobile number']/preceding-sibling::input
```

Comment: `//` means Xpath, I want CSS also.